# SQL Server MERGE statement reporting invalid column

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, t-sql

I have this `MERGE` statement that works fine on one database server and I need to deploy it to another database server for a different country's office. I used RedGate's SQL Compare and both databases have what is required.

```
MERGE dbo.MfgGrouping AS Target
USING
    (SELECT JC.job_number
         , JC.Quote_NO
         , PMG.MfgGroupingID
         , SR.Description
         , MG.GroupingNumber
         , MG.GroupingDesc
         , MG.Assigned
         , MG.AssignedDate
         , MG.AssignedBy
         , MG.[Priority]
         , P.Record_no
     FROM   dbo.Product AS P
           INNER JOIN dbo.ProductMfgGrouping AS PMG ON P.Record_no = PMG.Record_no
           INNER JOIN dbo.Job_Control AS JC ON P.Quote_NO = JC.Quote_NO
           LEFT OUTER JOIN dbo.MfgGrouping AS MG ON PMG.MfgGroupingID = MG.MfgGroupingID
           LEFT OUTER JOIN dbo.ShopRouting AS SR ON MG.ShopRoutingID = SR.ShopRoutingID
     WHERE  (JC.job_number = @SalesOrder)) AS Source
    ON(Target.MfgGroupingID = Source.MfgGroupingID)

    WHEN MATCHED
       THEN 
          UPDATE 
          SET Target.GroupingNumber = Source.GroupingNumber, 
              Target.Assigned = Source.Assigned, 
              Target.AssignedDate = Source.AssignedDate, 
              Target.AssignedBy = Source.AssignedBy

    WHEN NOT MATCHED BY TARGET
       THEN 
          INSERT(GroupingNumber, Assigned, AssignedDate, AssignedBy, Record_no) 
          VALUES(1, Source.Assigned, Source.AssignedDate, Source.AssignedBy, Source.Record_no);
```

The problem that I'm experiencing is that I get an error:

> invalid column name 'Record_no'

on the deployed database; but not on the original DB. Everything looks the same and good to me.

Can someone please shed some light on this?

The only difference is the original database is SQL Server 2014 and the deployed database is SQL Server 2008.

Thanks,
Jimmy

[image]

Comment: have you checked the table dbo.MfgGrouping to see if it has a column called Record_no?

Comment: I aggree with Kamran ,it looks dbo.MfgGrouping table doesn't belong Record_no column.

Comment: Why don't you try a manual insert on MfgGrouping ?

Comment: So as other have pointed the column doesn't seem to exist or did you try running this and got the error? If it's only based on the syntax it may be the column was added later on but information schemas are not yet updated

Comment: This is glaringly obvious to me now; yes, everyone is correct - Record_no does not exist for the MfgGrouping table.  @Sam - the tables were added beforehand so the information schema is updated.

Comment: I'm not sure why it's not flagged as an invalid column in the original DB?

Comment: Problem solved; thanks everyone.